# CSS problema con desbordamiento de texto en componente hijo - Angular

Tags: css, angular

He creado en angular un componente padre llamado **app-list-item** dentro de el hay dos componentes uno llamado **app-list-avatar** y el otro **app-list-content** el cual contiene en su interior dos componentes hijos **app-list-title** y  **app-list-subtitle**.

```
    <app-list-item slot-list>
          <app-list-avatar >
             <i class="mdi mdi-send"></i>
          </app-list-avatar>

          <app-list-content>
             <app-list-title>aqui titulo</app-list-title>
             <app-list-subtitle>aqui subtitulo</app-list-subtitle>
          </app-list-content>
     </app-list-item>
```

mi problema está en que el componente **app-list-title** y **app-list-subtitle** desbordan su texto y sobresale del componente **app-list-content** aun cuando este tiene un **overflow: hidden**

Estos son los estilos css usados en los componentes, uso tailwindcss:

*componente app-list-item*

```
  .item-list{@apply flex flex-nowrap items-center px-4 py-3 text-gray-800 overflow-hidden hover:bg-gray-200; }
```

*componente app-list-content*

```
   .list-content{@apply flex flex-col ml-2 overflow-hidden;}
```

*componente app-list-title*

```
   .list-title{@apply px-2 font-medium  truncate overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden;}
```

*componente app-list-subtitle*

```
    .list-subtitle{@apply px-2 text-sm text-gray-400 truncate overflow-ellipsis ;}
```

El resultado obtenido es este:

[image: Como se observa hay un desborde del titulo y subtitulo, y deberia mostrar puntos en vez de continuar el texto]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque sucede esto, si en cada componente le estoy asignando una propiedad de overflow: hidden;

El resultado que espero obtener es que se le asigne los puntos al final.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]